# Unable to access file .vmtx (Jenkins plugin vSphere Cloud)

Tags: jenkins, cloud, vsphere

I am using Jenkins version 2.236 (but also tried with 2.263.1), vSphere Plugin version 2.24, vSphere Client version 6.7.0
When i start my job and go to jenkins logs i see that below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd9Ua.png)

This vmtx file is avaliable on vSphere client (i can download it, delete it, move by hands no problem), i also can Clone VM from template manualy, but plugin can't get access to it and clone it, it has an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aekfg.png)
Please help, how to avoid this problem?

```css
Unexpected exception encountered while provisioning agent dynamic3fofguaybl6yiwkjfe7jk5zm9
com.vmware.vim25.CannotAccessVmConfig
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.XmlGenDom.fromXml(XmlGenDom.java:253)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.XmlGenDom.fromXml(XmlGenDom.java:363)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.XmlGenDom.fromXml(XmlGenDom.java:363)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.XmlGenDom.fromXml(XmlGenDom.java:363)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.XmlGenDom.fromXml(XmlGenDom.java:356)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.XmlGenDom.fromXML(XmlGenDom.java:233)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.XmlGenDom.fromXML(XmlGenDom.java:124)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.SoapClient.unMarshall(SoapClient.java:253)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.WSClient.invoke(WSClient.java:96)
    at com.vmware.vim25.ws.VimStub.retrieveProperties(VimStub.java:106)
    at com.vmware.vim25.mo.PropertyCollector.retrieveProperties(PropertyCollector.java:98)
    at com.vmware.vim25.mo.ManagedObject.retrieveObjectProperties(ManagedObject.java:146)
    at com.vmware.vim25.mo.ManagedObject.getCurrentProperty(ManagedObject.java:167)
    at com.vmware.vim25.mo.Task.getTaskInfo(Task.java:51)
Caused: org.jenkinsci.plugins.vsphere.tools.VSphereException: vSphere Error: Couldn't clone "ubuntu-18.04-dynamic-node-for-test". Clone task ended with status error.
Unable to access the virtual machine configuration: Unable to access file [esxi-datastore_nvme] ubuntu-18.04-dynamic-node-for-test/ubuntu-18.04-dynamic-node-for-test.vmtx
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.vsphere.tools.VSphere.newVSphereException(VSphere.java:1151)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.vsphere.tools.VSphere.cloneOrDeployVm(VSphere.java:287)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.vSphereCloudSlaveTemplate.provision(vSphereCloudSlaveTemplate.java:428)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.vSphereCloudSlaveTemplate.provision(vSphereCloudSlaveTemplate.java:403)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.vSphereCloud$VSpherePlannedNode.provisionNewNode(vSphereCloud.java:534)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.vSphereCloud$VSpherePlannedNode.access$100(vSphereCloud.java:496)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.vSphereCloud$VSpherePlannedNode$1.call(vSphereCloud.java:510)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.vSphereCloud$VSpherePlannedNode$1.call(vSphereCloud.java:506)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:71)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Hey and welcome. Can you share the image content (the text) as code blocks? So it is easier to read and copy & paste it for searching.

Comment: @KargWare hello, i inserted the code.

Comment: i have same result with terraform and vsphere-iso problem, do you find any solution to this?

Comment: i cannot explain why, but i figured out how to fix the problem.
In my terraform configuration,  i had to specify in which datastore the vm is cloned/created.
I recently added one ESXI to my vSphere cluster, whereas before i was using one esxi where all datastores was.